# How to create a color ramp to change the color of a svg image in arcgis javascript api

Tags: javascript, symbology, rendering, svg, color-ramp

I have an SVG image to create a `PictureMarkerSymbol` for a feature. How to create a color ramp to change the SVG color based on a criteria, like a attribute on my feature?

The idea is like that:

```
var mySymbol = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol("../resources/img/myimage.svg", 32, 32).setOffset(0, 8);
var renderer = new esri.renderers.SimpleRenderer(mySymbol);

renderer.changeColor ( field, colors, criteria )
```